# How can I import these modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to import certain files from `C:\Panda3D-1.7.2\otp\ai`

I have [the folder](http://i.gyazo.com/9d686eb19d3953dbc7cb267e448e6535.png) `C:\Panda3D-1.7.2\`, and inside that folder, there are many other folders.

How can I specify the `ai` folder and import different `.py` files from inside it?

Comment: Have a look at the [modules documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the structure contained under `C:\Panda3D-1.7.2\otp` is a valid [Python package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) (basically there's an `__init__.py` file inside) you can import those *files* (modules) like so:

```
import otp.ai.foo
```

For this to work you should have `C:\Panda3D-1.7.2` in your [**PYTHONPATH**](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) or you could add it programmatically using `sys.path.append`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Panda3D-1.7.2")
```

Take a look at the [Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) tutorial on the official Python docs, specially the [The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) subsection. It explains everything in a clear and concise way ;)